# Get XML attribute name (not value) using PHP

Tags: php, xml

```
     <Parent>
  <Children idontknowthis='thisisnotmyquestion'>
   <x>1</x>
   <x>2</x>
   <x>3</x>
   <x>4</x>
  </Children>
 </Parent>
```

Example an .xml file I'm working with below. My script would need to establish "id" by itself (to be clear I can already get bk109)...

```
   <book id="bk109">
      <author>Kress, Peter</author>
      <title>Paradox Lost</title>
      <genre>Science Fiction</genre>
      <price>6.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
      <description>After an inadvertant trip through a Heisenberg
      Uncertainty Device, James Salway discovers the problems 
      of being quantum.</description>
   </book>
```

For the purpose of an XML import script in PHP which will import many different XML files. How do I obtain the attribute names? (i.e. "id")

Comment: Can you show us the code used to get `bk109`?

Comment: I was using something like...          foreach( $xml5 as $header => $book ) { 
   
            echo $book->attributes().'<br>';

        }

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reading about the topic in the manual (or using the search here on site).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SimpleXML's `attributes` property.

See http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php